# Accessing Logged in User Profile for Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am new to Windows development, after searching through available topics without luck I figure I would ask my question...

I am developing an app in which I need to gain access to the logged in user profile to pull the name and picture, maybe other information like email and such if I have access to it.

Are there API's exposed to access the Logged in users profile information?

Thank you

Comment: Is this a Windows Store Application or a Desktop application?

Comment: This will be a Windows Store Application

Answer (score 0):

you can use `UserPrincipal Class` if your programming under .NET 4.5 or above!!
this class is under

[System.DirectoryServices Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145037.aspx)

[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

[UserPrincipal.Current Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.current.aspx)

just check documentation for above class and namespace

Comment: Thank you, I will look through these classes

Answer (score 0):

Given your recent comment about it being Windows Store apps, I'm presuming you mean access to the logged in Microsoft account (aka Windows Live ID).

Here are a couple of resources that should help:

1. The Build presentation [Powering your apps with Microsoft Accounts](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-138)
2. The [Windows 8 app developer blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/03/14/bring-single-sign-on-and-skydrive-to-your-windows-8-apps-with-the-live-sdk.aspx)
3. [Live services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770846.aspx) on the [dev.windows.com](http://dev.windows.com) site